# Why does Fortran write to fort.x?

Tags: fortran, mpi, fortran90

I am doing a MPI-parallelized simulation with a Fortran 90 code and want to write some information to a file, called "logBubbles.out". In every timestep of the simulation, a certain number of lines shall be added to the specific file. My code looks like this:

```
open(UNIT=s_IOunitNumber,FILE='./logBubbles.out',STATUS='OLD',POSITION='append',ACTION='WRITE')
      write(s_IOunitNumber,*) bubbleindex,' ',this%ptrTime_%t_,' ',interfArea,' ',bubVol
close(s_IOunitNumber)
```

... where bubbleindex is an integer, and the rest are doubles.

However, when I run the simulation, only about 50% of the respective lines are added to `logBubbles.out`, while an additional file `fort.50` is created. It always includes just one line, which changes from time to time.
The parameter `s_IOunitNumber` is `50`.

I have tried various things but I cannot figure out why this happens. Is my write command wrong?

Additional info
Comiler -> mpif90
Environment -> OpenSUSE Leap 15.0

Entire subroutine:

```
!========================================================================================!
    subroutine computeInterfacialArea(this,vofb) 
        type(VOF), intent(in) ::this
        type(vofBlock), intent(in) :: vofb
        integer :: lbi,ubi,lbj,ubj,lbk,ubk,i,j,k,bubbleindex
        real(DP) :: dalphadx, dalphady, dalphadz, deltaS,interfArea,bubVol
        character(len=20) :: dirName

        bubbleindex=vofb%bn         !bn is the global bubble index of the vof block

        lbi = 1+lbound(vofb%stx,1)  !this value would be 1 too low because the grid indices are x staggered
        ubi = ubound(vofb%stx,1)    !all the other bounding values are correct
        lbj = lbound(vofb%stx,2)
        ubj = ubound(vofb%stx,2)
        lbk = lbound(vofb%stx,3)
        ubk = ubound(vofb%stx,3)

        interfArea=0.d0
        bubVol=0.d0

        do k=lbk,ubk
            do j=lbj,ubj
                do i=lbi,ubi
                    dalphadx=(vofb%c(i+1,j,k)-vofb%c(i-1,j,k))/(vofb%dxc(i+1)+vofb%dxc(i))  !central differences for dalpha/dx...
                    dalphady=(vofb%c(i,j+1,k)-vofb%c(i,j-1,k))/(vofb%dyc(j+1)+vofb%dyc(j))  !...dalpha/dy...
                    dalphadz=(vofb%c(i,j,k+1)-vofb%c(i,j,k-1))/(vofb%dzc(k+1)+vofb%dzc(k))  !...and dalpha/dz on a collocated grid
                    deltaS=sqrt(dalphadx*dalphadx+dalphady*dalphady+dalphadz*dalphadz)      !deltaS is the magnitude
                    interfArea=interfArea+vofb%dxf(i)*vofb%dyf(j)*vofb%dzf(k)*deltaS        !stepwise Volume integral of deltaS
                    bubVol=bubVol+vofb%dxf(i)*vofb%dyf(j)*vofb%dzf(k)*vofb%c(i,j,k)         !stepwise Volume integral of cvof for volume
                end do
            end do
        end do

        open(UNIT=s_IOunitNumber,FILE='./logBubbles.out',&
                 STATUS='OLD',POSITION='append',ACTION='WRITE')
            write(s_IOunitNumber,*) bubbleindex,' ',this%ptrTime_%t_,' ',interfArea,' ',bubVol
        close(s_IOunitNumber)


    end subroutine
!========================================================================================!
```

Comment: Are you writing from one MPI process or multiple processes? Maybe some deadlock?

Comment: I think it is no MPI error, if I just use write(*,*) it is correctly written to my standard log-File... I just want it to be in another file, everything else already worked...

Comment: We need the complete code. It is quite possible that you failed to open the file on one of the processes. Or that you close the file and still try to write into it afterwards. When you  do `write(50,...` and the unit is not open, it is written to `fort.50`.

Comment: Just write out the `STATUS` and see what happens when it goes wrong (maybe for the test also write the status value in the `bubbleindex` line).

Comment: How is `s_IOunitNumber` set? Where else is it used?

Comment: Hi, I added the entire subroutine. s_IOunitNumber is set once for the entire code, if I use 50 instead of it the result is the same. I just added the iostat return to the open command, seems to be zero all the time. However I already saw that the list is not perfectly formatted, sometimes two lines overlap as the single MPI tasks seem to write to the same file. Could that result in an error? I mean the log file (it worked there) does not have to be opened / closed, so maybe that is why it works there. If now various MPI processes open / close simultaneously this might lead to problems?

Comment: Would it be an option to open the file once in the beginning of the simulation, keep it opened, and close it only once the simulation is done? This is probably not a very elegant way to write out but if opening / closing is the problem it might help...

Comment: Well, using the same unit and same filename for multiple processes might not be the best option. There might be conflicts when you try to write to the same file from several processes in parallel.

Comment: Just try in your `subroutine computeInterfacialArea` to use e.g. 42 instead of  `s_IOunitNumber` (i.e. hard code! at least when you haven't used 42 for other outputs (in that case use another, unused, number) and see what happens.

Comment: As writing to the same file from various MPI tasks simultaneously was not successful with everything I tried I solved my issue by having each task writing to a seperate file, which in the end is not worse for my application. Thank you for all of your suggestions!

Comment: @tre95 If you need to write to one file from multiple ranks you should use MPI-IO. However, it makes much better sense with binary files.